# Change title of browser window in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is some code that I am using to populate a browser window with multiple tabs that point to the same website.

```
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.open('" + url + "');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('" + url + "');")
```

This code works and I don't have a problem with it per se, but I would like to be able to modify the tab titles because they will be used for monitoring network elements.  The rest of the code logs in each tab just fine, but since each tab will be monitoring a different set of network elements, I'd like the tab title to reflect that after the rest of the page is populated, so that my users will have an easier time with this tool.  I've seen some examples of this in different languages for Selenium, but I'm not sure how to implement this in Python.

Comment: Can you share the code for the non python.

Answer (score 1):

The tab title can be modified by assigning to `document.title` (not `window.title`)
in JavaScript, but first you need to switch to that window, and also make it
the active tab.

Switching between windows is easy: get a handle from `window_handles` and call
`drv.switch_to.window`. Changing the active tab can be done by sending
Ctrl-TAB.

Here's an example:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

drv = webdriver.Firefox()

# Get the website
url = 'https://8.8.8.8'
drv.get(url)
sleep(3)
w0 = drv.window_handles[0]

# Create new window, make it the active tab
drv.execute_script("window.open('" + url + "');")
drv.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
sleep(3)
w1 = drv.window_handles[1]

# Change title on new window
drv.switch_to.window(w1)
drv.execute_script('document.title = "My New Title"')

# Switch back to w0 if needed
```